# How to mean values based on row passed valeus in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF:

```
DATE         TEAM   PTS  MEAN_PTS
1-1-2015     x      50      1?
1-1-2015     y      60      2?
2-1-2015     x      70      3?
2-1-2015     y      80      4?
```

I'm want the columns MEAN_PTS to be mean value of the pass PTS column based on the team. Like, 1? should be 50, 2? should be 60, 3? should be 60,  4? should be 70

I tried something like that:

```
DF['MEAN_PTS'] = 0
for i in range(0, len(DF)):
       cont = 1
       for line in range(0, len(DF)):
              if line != i:
                     if DF.loc[line, 'TEAM'] == DF.loc[i, 'TEAM']:
                            cont += 1
                            DF[line, 'MEAN_PTS'] = (DF[line, 'PTS'] + DF[i, 'MEAN_PTS']*(cont-1)) / cont
```

But it dosent work. Return: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: See the first answer in duplicate link, you want `groupby` and `rolling average`

Comment: Thank you SO MUTH!!!!! Follow the answear:
df['MEAN_PTS'] = df.groupby('TEAM')['PTS'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())